# iTunes Song's Preview image not displaying

Tags: ios, iphone, itunes, ios-extensions, share-extension

I integrated share extension in my application.

I am able to see share extension of my application in other apps, such as iTunes, Spotify etc.

Getting url of song to display in editable textview. But what issue I am facing in when I share song from spotify then it is loading preview image of that song.(Refer Screenshot) [image]

and When I share song from iTunes then it is not loading image of that song(Refer Screenshot). I am not sure what I am doing wrong. If anybody can help please.

Also I wanted to make this link non-editable. I am not getting any work around for that as well. Want to make it look like facebook share pop up.

[image].

Below is my Code snippet,

```
if let item = extensionContext?.inputItems.first as? NSExtensionItem,
            let itemProvider = item.attachments?.first as? NSItemProvider,
            itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier("public.url") {

            itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: "public.url", options: nil) { (url, error) in
                if let shareURL = url as? URL {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.textView.text = String(format:"%@",shareURL as CVarArg)
                        self.loadPreviewView()
                    }
                }
            }
            print("Print item : \(item), \(String(describing: extensionContext))")
        }
```

Comment: I think sharing url as text, thats why it's not rendering image, just set as NSURL  and try for share dialog.

Comment: @VelmuruganS If this is the case then how it is working in spotify..
Also how to set url in textview. I need to display as text only in textview.

Comment: they also set text as well, is that image changing while editing that url ? (due to i can't able to install that app).

Comment: Nopp image is not changing while editing that url.

Comment: hope image is set manually with text. just share that text in twitter and see, if you see separate image below the post, then they used image, or if you found link with it url is setting.